# Not able to center an a in a li

Tags: css

I am trying to center an `a` within a `li` in a navigation menu. IT is not working. Here is my relevant css:

```
#access ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 4px solid #2980b9;
    top: 55px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 190px;

}

#access li:hover
{
background: #2980b9;    
}

#access a {
display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Any thoughts on this?

For the HTML see the nag bar in http://phasetransfercatalysis.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the element to be explicitly sized for that trick to work.

```
a{
    dispaly:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zyw6y/2/

Comment: He has declared that, the issue is `position: absolute;` or he just needs `text-align: center;`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options at least.

First option, set a width to your `a` like so

```
#access a {
   width: 60%;
}
```

---

Second option, you can rework your code and set `text-align: center` on the parent which is the `li`, and make the `a` inline-block so that it follows the orders from `li` to be aligned centered.

```
#access li {
   text-align: center;
}

#access a {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: and don't forget to set a width for the <a>